# Parameterized class without parameters?

Tags: java, generics, parameterized-types

In an Android framework I am trying to understand, I find a statement like this:

```
public Call<GeneralResponseSO> performApiCall(/*...*/) {
    // ...
}
```

But `GeneralResponseSO` is defined like this:

```
public class GeneralResponseSO<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Shouldn't the api method specify which type `T` is? I can't seem to grasp why the compiler doesn't give an error, and what type `T` then is.

Or does the compiler do magic to filter out all the generics from the class? So that all variables/methods that use `T` are removed? I wouldn't expect the Java compiler to perform such magic though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: The compiler should give you a warning. Heed them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

A generic class / interface without type parameter is `Raw type`.

Raw type is unchecked during compile (and you may see warning in IDE such as Intellij) and may cause exception at runtime.

> Note: Example.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

[You can read more here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)